# BeautifulSoup "Scraping" using their name and their id

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup but I'm unsure how to correctly make use of find, findall and the other functions...

If I have:

```
<div class="hey"></div>
```

Using: `soup.find_all("div", class_="hey")`

Will correctly find the div in question, however I do not know how to do it for the following:

```
<h3 id="me"></h3> # Find this one via "h3" and "id"

<li id="test1"></li># Find this one via "li" and "id"

<li custom="test2321"></li># Find this one via "li" and "custom"

<li id="test1" class="tester"></li> # Find this one via "li" and "class"

<ul class="here"></ul> # Find this one via "ul" and "class"
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<h3 id="me"></h3>
<li id="test1"></li>
<li custom="test2321"></li>
<li id="test1" class="tester"></li>
<ul class="here"></ul>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# This tells BS to look at all the h3 tags, and find the ones that have an ID of me
# This however should not be done because IDs are supposed to be unique, so
# soup.find_all(id="me") should be used
one = soup.find_all("h3", {"id": "me"})
print one

# Same as above, if something has an ID, just use the ID
two = soup.find_all("li", {"id": "test1"})  # ids should be unique
print two

# Tells BS to look at all the li tags and find the node with a custom attribute
three = soup.find_all("li", {"custom": "test2321"})
print three

# Again ID, should have been enough
four = soup.find_all("li", {"id": "test1", "class": "tester"})
print four

# Look at ul tags, and find the one with a class attribute of "here"
four = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "here"})
print four
```

Output:

```
[<h3 id="me"></h3>]
[<li id="test1"></li>, <li class="tester" id="test1"></li>]
[<li custom="test2321"></li>]
[<li class="tester" id="test1"></li>]
[<ul class="here"></ul>]
```

[This](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) should provide the required documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From help:

```
In [30]: soup.find_all?
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:
<bound method BeautifulSoup.find_all 
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py
Definition: soup.find_all(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Extracts a list of Tag objects that match the given
criteria.  You can specify the name of the Tag and any
attributes you want the Tag to have.

The value of a key-value pair in the 'attrs' map can be a
string, a list of strings, a regular expression object, or a
callable that takes a string and returns whether or not the
string matches for some custom definition of 'matches'. The
same is true of the tag name.
```

So, you could pass attributes as dictionary, or just as named argument:

```
In [31]: soup.find_all("li", custom="test2321")
Out[31]: [<li custom="test2321"></li>]

In [32]: soup.find_all("li", {"id": "test1", "class": ""})
Out[32]: [<li id="test1"></li>]
```

Comment: I just put everything in `attrs` :P. Easiest way for me :P