# Using Python & BeautifulSoup to scrape HTML tag identifier values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm still learning Python, and have been scraping some web data with BeautifulSoup, my question: is it possible to scrape tag ID values?

Maybe it's better to give an example, the HTML code I'm working with looks like this:

```
<A CLASS="someClass" uniqueID="someValue" anotherID="someOtherValue">
Here is the data I can scrape right now.
</A>
```

So from the above example, I can successfully scrape whats between the A tag, but I don't know how to grab the value of "uniqueID" and "anotherID" that exists *inside the A tag*.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468438/beautifulsoup-scraping-using-their-name-and-their-id

Comment: Use the `get()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `attributes` of an `element`, you can use the `.get()` method (`python3`), i.e.:

```
<A CLASS="someClass" uniqueID="someValue" anotherID="someOtherValue">
Here is the data I can scrape right now.
</A>
```

...

```
_as = xmlSoup.find_all('a')

for a in _as :
    print(a.get('CLASS'))
    print(a.get('uniqueID'))
    print(a.get('anotherID'))
    print(a.text))
```

The above will loop all `a` tags in the html and print the specified attributes of each one.

Comment: Care to comment the down-vote?

Comment: You made the edit, I was in the process of commenting.
Worth noting he hasn't explicitly requested to find_all.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the link in the comment I posted but what I think you are trying to do is something like this;

```
soup.find("a", {"uniqueID": "someValue"})
```

If you were to post an example of your code I could tailor this but as you haven't it's rather generic.